# Ruby on Rails Image in HTML code

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make an image pop up in my Ruby on Rails website. I am using the HTML doc to be my homepage and when I type in this code (below) it doesn't appear. I have been searching all over for the different way to call it but I haven't been able to generate the image on my site. Sorry I am also new to SE so if I need to add something to this please be patient and kind.

Am I missing a gemfile that I need to render images?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<p>Welcome to <%= @owner.name %>.</p>

<div class="row">
  <div class="large-3 columns">
<a href="http://www.DeremaHelp.com" target="_self"> 
   <img src="/home/nitrous/code/Derema_Help/app/assets/images/brands/ancor.png" alt="Ancor" border="0"/> 
</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should be using a image_tag http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag

Comment: Try to put this image in the `public` folder and after just put `ancor.png` to the `src="`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you

```
<a href="http://www.DeremaHelp.com">
    <img src="/images/ancor.png"/>
</a>
```

or

```
<%= image_tag("ancor.png") %>
```